# Admin side login template override, extra field on login

Tags: joomla-api, joomla3.8

I want to add an extra field onto the admin login page. I already have the front end login override sorted, just having trouble with the admin side.

I copied file.

```
administrator/components/com_login/views/login/tmpl/default.php
```

To

```
adminitrator/templates/isis/html/com_login/login/default.php
```

It looks like the override works because, if I echo in the override file. example.

```
echo '<div>fff</div>';
```

The fff displays on the login screen on the admin side.

The problem is the fff is generated outside the form part, so it doesn't help adding my field in the above override file.

The form part are created with the following 2 lines.

```
$loginmodule = LoginModelLogin::getLoginModule('mod_login');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($loginmodule, array('style' => 'rounded', 'id' => 'section-box'));
```

How can I add a field to the login form without changing core joomla files.

Not sure if there is a plugin event for this situation. An plugin event will suite my situation better than an override.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file to override is `administrator/modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php`. Note that login forms do not support extending (thus the need for overrides). This means any field you add will not be used for login process. You can still make use of the fields by using a system plugin that runs on `login` task.